# Recursively calculate values in data frame in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

I am working with python and pandas to calculate an exponentially-weighted moving average on a crypto price.  I am having trouble working out how to perform the recursive calculation on the dataframe.

For simplicity, I just have a dataframe df with column "log_rtn".  It looks like this when I print it:

```
0        NaN
1     0.0000
2    -0.0006
3     0.0001
4    -0.0001
5     0.0005
6     0.0002
7     0.0001
8    -0.0003
9    -0.0005
10    0.0001
11    0.0002
12    0.0005
13   -0.0002
14    0.0000
15    0.0003
16   -0.0005
17    0.0007
18    0.0002
19    0.0005
```

For each value in df['log_rtn'], I need to apply this formula:

`L*r(t-1)2 + (1-L)*rt2`

where L is a known constant and r is the log_rtn.  So the first term is referring to the previous row.

Comment: Check out [pd.Series.ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ewm.html).

Comment: also, to manually implement it, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html